# Google maps for application with sensitive data in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

I'm developing a map solution for a number of private buildings which does not want their floor plan or any other geographic details about their building being made public by google. I'm currently planning to plot their floor plan by drawing custom polygons on top of google maps. My concern is - Will the data I plot in google maps be sent to google servers or evaluated by them in any way? It is known that google does collect usage data. I'm not sure as to what extent they do that, or what exactly they collect. Can you clarify on this issue? And if an issue persists, can you give me some pointers to avoid this issue? I hope the situation is clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

That kind of data is not (currently) sent to Google's servers. I don't know of any plans for that to happen, but I don't want to say that it will never happen, either.

What *is* sent to Google's servers: statistics about the usage of features of the API. This is collected so that we can focus on improving the features that are highest value to our developers.

Please do read the Terms of Service carefully. Some sections that might be of interest:

1. [Section 4](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_4_3)
2. [Section 9](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_1_1)